# Maximize yield given two products and price

Tags: derivatives

Just started learning to use derivatives to apply to real world, and this homework problem is really tripping me up, and getting a formula to start is even giving me a bunch of trouble.

If fertilizer made from N pounds of nitrogen and P pounds of phosphate is used on an acre of farmland, then the yield of corn (in bushels per acre) is 
Y=7.5 + 6.5N + 0.7P - 0.001N^2 - 0.002P^2 +0.001NP
A farmer intends to spend $30 per acre on fertilizer. If nitrogen costs 25 cents/lb and phosphate costs 20 cents/lb, what is the combination of N and P that produces the most corn.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try and write this problem as an equation.

For optimization problems, the template you might have in mind:

$\max\limits_{x,y}{f(x,y)}$

Subject to

$g(x,y)=0$

What are we trying to maximize? What are the choice variables (the variable we have control over--the variables we can choose), and how do they affect what we're trying to maximize? How is our choice constrained--can we pick any combination of choice variables we'd like?